# HTML after Pseudo-element not showing as intended

Tags: html, css, position, pseudo-element

```css
* {
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.text--bigtitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.border--short {
    position: relative;
}

.border--short::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    color: red;
    margin-left: -20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="border--short text--bigtitle">Short Border</p>
</div>
```

I want to achieve a short bottom border instead of a full-width bottom border under a title using CSS and HTML.

I have tried using position:absolute to position the after element under the title text with the width desired. However, the bottom border is not showing at all. My code is as shown below:

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, thank heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `color` property to `background-color` property of `.border--short::after`. `color` property is used to change the font color of the text. `background-color` is used to change the background color. thanks

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.text--bigtitle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.border--short {
  position: relative;
}

.border--short::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: -20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="border--short text--bigtitle">Short Border</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I was confused with border-bottom and an actually block. Changing color to background-color solves the problem. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is how you need..

```css
* {
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.text--bigtitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.border--short {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.border--short::after {
        content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="border--short text--bigtitle">Short Border</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.text--bigtitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.border--short {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.border--short::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 40%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 30%; /* 50 % minus half the width */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="border--short text--bigtitle">Short Border</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this once it will work and if you don't want text center remove `text-align: center` form class `.wrapper`.

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.text--bigtitle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text--bigtitle::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="text--bigtitle">Short Border</p>
</div>
```

Thank You...